# Automating Text Insertion into Dynamic Input Field in Instagram using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, instagram

I'm creating an extension for *Google Chrome* to help automate the work of my wife, who spends too much time on Instagram. I'm new to *JS* and *extension* coding, but have done something similar in *Python* for other purposes.

I need to insert prepared text into the message field in Instagram DM`s page. Although the code works fine on the test page, there is a problem on DM page which is generated dynamically: when user types the first character, Instagram loads the actual input field. It seems like I've already tried every insertion method, they aren't work.

Currently I'm trying to emulate keyboard input **character by character** but it hasn't worked yet. I would have given up, but I came across the *BrowserFlow* extension that successfully copes with this. By the way, I would use it, but it is too complex for a girl and I essentially only need this one function. I dug a little deeper and realized that *BrowserFlow* also inserts text **character by character**, but does it in current tab debugging mode. Can someone explain how to implement this if this is the secret?

My code looks like this:

```js
  async function typeText(text, element, msDelay) {

    consoleLog('Typing text: ' + text);  
    if (!element) {
      consoleLog('No active element found');
      return; 
    }

    consoleLog('Element in focus obtained');
  
    for (let char of text) {
     
      let keydownEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
        bubbles: true, 
        key: char, 
        char: char, 
        shiftKey: false 
      });
      element.dispatchEvent(keydownEvent);
      consoleLog(`Keydown event dispatched for character: ${char}`);
  

      let keypressEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keypress", { 
        bubbles: true, 
        key: char, 
        char: char, 
        shiftKey: false 
      });
      element.dispatchEvent(keypressEvent);
      consoleLog(`Keypress event dispatched for character: ${char}`);
  

      if ('value' in element) {
        element.value += char; // Для input элементов.
        consoleLog(`Added character to value: ${char}`);
      } else {
        element.textContent += char; 
        consoleLog(`Added character to textContent: ${char}`);
      }
  
     
      let keyupEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", { 
        bubbles: true, 
        key: char, 
        char: char, 
        shiftKey: false 
      });
      element.dispatchEvent(keyupEvent);
      consoleLog(`Keyup event dispatched for character: ${char}`);
  
     
      let inputEvent = new Event("input", {
        bubbles: true
      });
      element.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
      consoleLog(`Input event dispatched`);
  
      
      if (msDelay) {
        consoleLog(`Delaying for ${msDelay} ms`);
        await delay(msDelay);
      }
    }



        if (element !== null) {
            const text = "Hello, World!";
            const msDelay = 200; 
            typeText(text, element, msDelay);
        } else {
            consoleLog('No active element found, retrying in 2 seconds');
            setTimeout(tryTipeInElement, 2000);
        }`
```

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: No way I've missed it! I was told by the VS code that this method  was marked as deprecated. But it works! Thank you!